# How do I access this data in handlebars?

Tags: jquery, ajax, handlebars.js

Currently accessing and appending an AJAX response like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $products = $('#products');
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:9000/api/products/',
    success: function(products) {
        $.each(products, function(i, product) {
            $products.append('<li><p>' + product.name + '</p><p>' + product.id + '</p></li>');
        });
    }

});
```

});

But having a little trouble accessing it in handlebars. 
Here is the JSON response I am getting:

```
[{"id":112502,"code":"501.161655","name":"S8000 FOLIAGE PACK","descriptions":{"short":"Men's Shoe","long":"Men's shoe. The retro running S8000 model is presented in an unexpected version, following the trend of camouflage prints. It has been reinterpreted with a foliage print which strongly characterises the upper and it nearly covers it all."},"price":{"sell":67.5,"currency":"€"},"images":{"small":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/501.161655_30044_small.jpg","medium":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/501.161655_30044_medium.jpg","big":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/501.161655_30044_big.jpg"},"options":[{"name":"Size","values":[{"name":"6.5"},{"name":"7"},{"name":"7.5"},{"name":"8.5"}]}]},{"id":90645,"code":"501.159877","name":"CONDOR REPTILE","descriptions":{"short":"Unisex Shoe","long":"Basket inspired, the sneaker Condor is developed in soft suede leather with leather inserts enriched  by outline logo in contrast color and by reptile inserts on the backcounter. Available in two different color combination."},"price":{"sell":42.5,"original":85,"currency":"€"},"images":{"small":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15987700001_C5409_small_501_159877.jpg","medium":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15987700001_C5409_medium_501_159877.jpg","big":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15987700001_C5409_big_501_159877.jpg"},"options":[{"name":"Size","values":[{"name":"3"},{"name":"3.5"},{"name":"4"},{"name":"4.5"},{"name":"5"},{"name":"5.5"},{"name":"6"},{"name":"7.5"},{"name":"8"},{"name":"8.5"},{"name":"9.5"},{"name":"10"},{"name":"10.5"},{"name":"11"},{"name":"11.5"},{"name":"12"}]},{"name":"Color","values":[{"name":"Beige Oyster","images":{"small":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15987700001_25043_small_501_159877.jpg","medium":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15987700001_25043_medium_501_159877.jpg","big":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15987700001_25043_big_501_159877.jpg","color":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15987700001_25043_color_501_159877.jpg"}},{"name":"Green Conifer / Green Flash","images":{"color":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15987700001_C5409_color_501_159877.jpg","big":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15987700001_C5409_big_501_159877.jpg","medium":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15987700001_C5409_medium_501_159877.jpg","small":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15987700001_C5409_small_501_159877.jpg"}}]}]},{"id":129483,"code":"501.159657_20859_20900","name":"GAME L HIGH WAXED","descriptions":{"short":"Unisex Shoe","long":"Mid-cut shoes Inspired by the 70's tennis world, in full-grain leather with applied leather logo.  Personalised and vulcanised box sole with waxing treatment."},"price":{"sell":50,"original":100,"currency":"€"},"images":{"small":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/501.159657_55086_small_501_159657.jpg","medium":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/501.159657_55086_medium_501_159657.jpg","big":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/501.159657_55086_big_501_159657.jpg"},"options":[{"name":"Size","values":[{"name":"3.5"},{"name":"4.5"},{"name":"5"},{"name":"5.5"},{"name":"6"},{"name":"6.5"},{"name":"7"},{"name":"7.5"},{"name":"8"},{"name":"8.5"},{"name":"9.5"},{"name":"10.5"},{"name":"11.5"}]},{"name":"Color","values":[{"name":"Advent Violet","images":{"color":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/501.159657_55086_color_501_159657.jpg","small":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/501.159657_55086_small_501_159657.jpg","medium":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/501.159657_55086_medium_501_159657.jpg","big":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/501.159657_55086_big_501_159657.jpg"}},{"name":"Blue Caspian Sea / White","images":{"color":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/501.159657_C3635_color_501_159657.jpg","small":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/501.159657_C3635_small_501_159657.jpg","medium":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/501.159657_C3635_medium_501_159657.jpg","big":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/501.159657_C3635_big_501_159657.jpg"}}]}]},{"id":138417,"code":"501.158623_2755_14512_19119_5964_20868_20872_12052_12072_12041_1","name":"TITAN II","descriptions":{"short":"Unisex Sports Shoe","long":"Inspired by the 80s running shoes seen on the feet of the most famous athletes. Characterised by the bidensity midsole, shock absorber on the rear and flex point, highlighted by contrasting E.V.A. bands. Touched-up materials and colours for a fresher, sportier look."},"price":{"sell":36,"original":90,"currency":"€"},"images":{"small":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/501.158623_70429_small.jpg","medium":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/501.158623_70429_medium.jpg","big":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/501.158623_70429_big.jpg"},"options":[{"name":"Size","values":[{"name":"3.5"},{"name":"4"},{"name":"4.5"},{"name":"6"},{"name":"6.5"},{"name":"7"},{"name":"8"},{"name":"9"},{"name":"9.5"},{"name":"10.5"},{"name":"11"},{"name":"11.5"},{"name":"12"},{"name":"13"}]},{"name":"Color","values":[{"name":"Coffee Bean","images":{"small":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/501.158623_30042_02_big_small_501_158623.jpg","medium":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/501.158623_30042_02_big_medium_501_158623.jpg","big":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/501.158623_30042_02_big_big_501_158623.jpg","color":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/501.158623_30042_02_big_color_501_158623.jpg"}},{"name":"Ash Grey / Blue Denim","images":{"color":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15862300001_C4959_color_501_158623.jpg","small":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15862300001_C4959_small_501_158623.jpg","medium":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15862300001_C4959_medium_501_158623.jpg","big":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15862300001_C4959_big_501_158623.jpg"}},{"name":"Sky-Bl Malibu' / Red","images":{"small":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15862300001_C5295_small_501_158623.jpg","medium":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15862300001_C5295_medium_501_158623.jpg","big":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15862300001_C5295_big_501_158623.jpg","color":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15862300001_C5295_color_501_158623.jpg"}},{"name":"Dark Gull Grey / Coffee Bean","images":{"small":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/501.158623_C5576_02_big_small_501_158623.jpg","medium":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/501.158623_C5576_02_big_medium_501_158623.jpg","big":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/501.158623_C5576_02_big_big_501_158623.jpg","color":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/501.158623_C5576_02_big_color_501_158623.jpg"}},{"name":"Grey Alaska / Fer.red Italy","images":{"small":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/501.158623_C5755_02_big_small_501_158623.jpg","medium":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/501.158623_C5755_02_big_medium_501_158623.jpg","big":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/501.158623_C5755_02_big_big_501_158623.jpg","color":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/501.158623_C5755_02_big_color_501_158623.jpg"}}]}]},{"id":74497,"code":"501.159663","name":"CONDOR CAMO WAXED","descriptions":{"short":"Unisex Shoe","long":"Diadora basket inspiered men's shoe. An interpretation in line with the trends for a classic by Diadora. The whole effect is enhanced by a waxed treatment and studs in application."},"price":{"sell":45,"original":90,"currency":"€"},"images":{"big":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15966300001_C5441_big_501_159663.jpg","medium":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15966300001_C5441_medium_501_159663.jpg","small":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15966300001_C5441_small_501_159663.jpg","color":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15966300001_C5441_color_501_159663.jpg"},"options":[{"name":"Size","values":[{"name":"3"},{"name":"3.5"},{"name":"4"},{"name":"4.5"},{"name":"5.5"},{"name":"6"},{"name":"6.5"},{"name":"7"},{"name":"8"},{"name":"10.5"},{"name":"11.5"},{"name":"12"}]},{"name":"Color","values":[{"name":"Burnt Olive Green","images":{"color":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15966300001_70431_color_501_159663.jpg","small":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15966300001_70431_small_501_159663.jpg","medium":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15966300001_70431_medium_501_159663.jpg","big":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15966300001_70431_big_501_159663.jpg"}},{"name":"Gray / Beige Ivory","images":{"big":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15966300001_C5441_big_501_159663.jpg","medium":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15966300001_C5441_medium_501_159663.jpg","color":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15966300001_C5441_color_501_159663.jpg","small":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15966300001_C5441_small_501_159663.jpg"}}]}]},{"id":77666,"code":"501.159159","name":"MI BASKET SHARK","descriptions":{"short":"Unisex  Shoe","long":"Summer restyling of the Mi Basket, the iconic Diadora  basket shoes, in a fresh and modern key. The shoes upper is completely in nylon with leather inserts. Available in three different colorway."},"price":{"sell":42.5,"original":85,"currency":"€"},"images":{"small":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15915900001_C5154_02_secondbig_159159000ok01_small_501_159159.jpg","medium":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15915900001_C5154_02_secondbig_159159000ok01_medium_501_159159.jpg","big":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15915900001_C5154_02_secondbig_159159000ok01_big_501_159159.jpg"},"options":[{"name":"Size","values":[{"name":"4.5"},{"name":"5"},{"name":"5.5"},{"name":"6"},{"name":"6.5"},{"name":"7"},{"name":"7.5"},{"name":"8"},{"name":"8.5"},{"name":"9"},{"name":"9.5"},{"name":"10"},{"name":"10.5"},{"name":"11"},{"name":"11.5"},{"name":"12"}]},{"name":"Color","values":[{"name":"Sky-Blue Clear Water","images":{"big":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15915900001_65113_02_biokg_big_501_159159.jpg","medium":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15915900001_65113_02_biokg_medium_501_159159.jpg","small":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15915900001_65113_02_biokg_small_501_159159.jpg","color":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15915900001_65113_02_biokg_color_501_159159.jpg"}},{"name":"Navy / Atollo Sky-Blue","images":{"big":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15915900001_C5154_02_secondbig_159159000ok01_big_501_159159.jpg","medium":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15915900001_C5154_02_secondbig_159159000ok01_medium_501_159159.jpg","small":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15915900001_C5154_02_secondbig_159159000ok01_small_501_159159.jpg","color":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15915900001_C5154_02_secondbig_159159000ok01_color_501_159159.jpg"}},{"name":"Flame Red / Vibrant Yellow","images":{"color":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15915900001_C5299_02_secondbig_1ok5915900001_color_501_159159.jpg","medium":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15915900001_C5299_02_secondbig_1ok5915900001_medium_501_159159.jpg","big":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15915900001_C5299_02_secondbig_1ok5915900001_big_501_159159.jpg","small":"http://cdn01.diadora.com/upload/diadora/images/15915900001_C5299_02_secondbig_1ok5915900001_small_501_159159.jpg"}}]}]}]
```

And what I have tried so far:

```
<script id="new-temp" type="text/template">
    {{#each product}}
    <h2>{{product.name}}</h2>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

But given the array in the response has no name I'm not sure if I'm accessing it right.
Pretty new to AJAX, and templating in general, would appreciate anyone helping me figure out how to access this?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

wrap your code in `{"products":products}`

```
<script id="new-temp" type="text/template">
    {{#each products}}
    <h2>{{name}}</h2>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

demo:http://jsfiddle.net/wguqcpd6/1/